# What is the value of {{ .Name }} in a packer template?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, packer

From [Packer doc](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/engine.html) I know that *{{ .Name }}* is a template variable, but for what value is replaced *{{ .Name }}* when template variable substitution is done?

I found several templates that use *{{ .Name }}* but I failed to found the doc the explain what value is backing *{{ .Name }}*

**I will appreciate if the answer point me to some doc.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to the [*name of the build*](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/builders.html#named-builds) which is the the *builder type* by default.

This isn't really clear from the docs so I opened [#5382](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/5382).

Answer (score 0):

I see that `{{.Name}}` resolves to this [virtualbox-ovf #vm_name](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-ovf.html#vm_name)
for `virtualbox-ovf` packer builder.